# Printing multi-line strings together

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have two `char` arrays, containing an image for `1` and an image for `0`.

```
char a[] =  "      &&\n"    
            "     & &\n"
            "    &  &\n"
            "   &   &\n"
            "  &    &\n"
            " &     &\n"
            "&      &\n"
            "       &\n"
            "       &\n"
            "       &\n"
            "       &\n"
            "       &\n"
            "       &\n";

char  b[] = "    & & & &    \n"
            "   &       &   \n"
            "  &         &  \n"
            " &           & \n"
            "&             &\n"
            "&             &\n"
            "&             &\n" 
            "&             &\n"
            "&             &\n"
            " &           & \n"
            "  &         &  \n"
            "   &       &   \n"
            "    & & & &    \n";
```

Now I want to print `10` (in big letters horizontally across the screen).

I tried to use this:

```
printf("%s  %s", a, b);
```

but this didn't work.  What should I have done?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Yes, it did work; it may not have produced the result you wanted, but it did work and did what you requested.  You've not really stated what result you wanted. It produced all of `a` on multiple lines, then 3 spaces and all of `b` on multiple lines. If you wanted one line from `a`, three spaces, and one line from `b` for each of the lines in the arrays, you have to loop and find the relevant segment of each variable and print that segment. It can be done; it isn't particularly difficult, though it isn't completely trivial either.

Comment: You need to remove the \n from the a and b character arrays, then use printf("%s %s\n", a, b); .

Answer (score 3):

What about something like:

```
char *a[] = { "      &&",
              "     & &",
              "    &  &",
              "   &   &",
              "  &    &",
              " &     &",
              "&      &",
              "       &",
              "       &",
              "       &",
              "       &",
              "       &",
              "       &"};

char *b[] = /* ... */; 

for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof a / sizeof *a; i++)
{
    printf("%s %s\n", a[i], b[i]);    
}
```

Comment: Redesigning the data structure is the easy way to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with a single printf as you have to interleave. What you have to do is to build it line by line. So you split each string by \n and then print

```
for (int i=0;i<sizeof lines_a / sizeof char*;i++)
    printf("%s %s\n", lines_a[i], lines_b[i]);
```

Comment: Splitting the arrays means that they can only be printed once.  Redesigning the data structure is a good idea, but not by zapping newlines with nulls (unless there's something else that tells you how many lines there are in each 'character').

Comment: I mean convert it into a new (reusable) array split at the newline character. (No need to write \0 into the source, however there is also ne reason to keep the source if you do only use it for this function). You can either do it programmatically (once and reuse it) or do it manually as @ouah answered.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't redesign your data structure the way [ouah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1119701/ouah) suggests in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27698072/15168) — which is the best way to deal with the problem (restructure the data to make it easy to process is very often a good way of proceeding) — then you need to find the end of the line in each of your 'big characters' and print each line in turn.

```
char *a_line = a;
char *b_line = b;
char *a_end;
char *b_end;

while ((a_end = strchr(a_line, '\n')) != 0 &&
       (b_end = strchr(b_line, '\n')) != 0)
{
    int a_len = a_end - a_line;
    int b_len = b_end - b_line;
    printf("%.*s   %.*s\n", a_len, a_line, b_len, b_line);
    a_line = a_end + 1;
    b_line = b_end + 1;
}
```

This loop stops when either `a` or `b` runs out of data.  With the sample arrays, they have the same number of lines, so there's no problem. If they had different numbers of lines, there'd be more work to do, too.  Similarly, the code assumes that the lines in each array are all the same length — as in the sample data.  If they were of different lengths, there'd be more work to do.

#### Complete test code

Note that I've removed the superfluous trailing blanks after the zero.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char a[] =  "      &&\n"    
                "     & &\n"
                "    &  &\n"
                "   &   &\n"
                "  &    &\n"
                " &     &\n"
                "&      &\n"
                "       &\n"
                "       &\n"
                "       &\n"
                "       &\n"
                "       &\n"
                "       &\n";

    char  b[] = "    & & & &    \n"
                "   &       &   \n"
                "  &         &  \n"
                " &           & \n"
                "&             &\n"
                "&             &\n"
                "&             &\n" 
                "&             &\n"
                "&             &\n"
                " &           & \n"
                "  &         &  \n"
                "   &       &   \n"
                "    & & & &    \n";

    char *a_line = a;
    char *b_line = b;
    char *a_end;
    char *b_end;

    while ((a_end = strchr(a_line, '\n')) != 0 &&
           (b_end = strchr(b_line, '\n')) != 0)
    {
        int a_len = a_end - a_line;
        int b_len = b_end - b_line;
        printf("%.*s   %.*s\n", a_len, a_line, b_len, b_line);
        a_line = a_end + 1;
        b_line = b_end + 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

#### Sample output

```
      &&       & & & &    
     & &      &       &   
    &  &     &         &  
   &   &    &           & 
  &    &   &             &
 &     &   &             &
&      &   &             &
       &   &             &
       &   &             &
       &    &           & 
       &     &         &  
       &      &       &   
       &       & & & &
```

Comment: Why this strchr crap? Isn't it better to split multiline strings into arrays as ouah suggested?

Comment: @Anonymous: I said that restructuring the data is the better choice, but if the rules are that you can't restructure the data, then this is one valid, neat and about as tidy as it can be way to deal with the presentation problem caused by the inappropriate data structure.  In other words, this answers the question that was asked, while also pointing out that there are alternative answers if the inputs can be revised and made more tractable.

Answer (score 0):

However you may not like this answer,but If you want your "1" is printed completely and then your "0" is printed, I suggest this way:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<Windows.h>
//gotoxy sets the cursor in position of int x,int y
void gotoxy(int x , int y){
   COORD newPosition={x,y};
   SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),newPosition);
}
//getxy gets current position of cursor and returns a COORD(a struct with fields of X and Y)
   COORD getxy(void){
   CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
   GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE ),&csbi);
   return csbi.dwCursorPosition;
}
int main(){
        char a[] =  "      &&\n"    
                    "     & &\n"
                    "    &  &\n"
                    "   &   &\n"
                    "  &    &\n"
                    " &     &\n"
                    "&      &\n"
                    "       &\n"
                    "       &\n"
                    "       &\n"
                    "       &\n"
                    "       &\n"
                    "       &";//I deleted '\n'

        char  b[] = "    & & & &    $"
                    "   &       &   $"
                    "  &         &  $"
                    " &           & $"
                    "&             &$"
                    "&             &$"
                    "&             &$" 
                    "&             &$"
                    "&             &$"
                    " &           & $"
                    "  &         &  $"
                    "   &       &   $"
                    "    & & & &    $";
        //your codes
        COORD first=getxy();//get position of first member of your "1"
        printf("%s",a);
        COORD last=getxy();//get position of last member of your "1"
        gotoxy(last.X+1,first.Y);
        COORD current=getxy();
        int i=0;
        while(b[i]!='\0'){
            if (b[i]=='$'){//this if statement does like '\n' but sets the cursor in your defined first_of_the_line
                gotoxy(current.X,current.Y+1);//current.X is your defined first_of_the_line
                current=getxy();
            }
            else
                printf("%c",b[i]);
            i++;

        }
    }
```